# AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute '_offset_zordered'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encountered this error while using Matplotlib3.7.1 to draw a 3D dynamic scatter plot. How can I solve it?
Here are some of the codes：

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

def init():
    plt.xlim(-30, 30)
    plt.ylim(-15, 45)
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')    
    sc = ax.scatter([], [], [], c='b', s=20, alpha=0.5, depthshade=True)
    return [sc]

def update(i):    
    print(xs, ys, zs)
    sc = ax.scatter(xs[:i], ys[:i], zs[:i], c='b', s=20, alpha=0.5, depthshade=True)
    return [sc]

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(xs), init_func=init, interval=50, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't have this problem when I run my script in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: I'm encountering this problem with 3.7.0 on a Mac with Homebrew-installed libraries.  (your code isn't copy-paste-runnable, so not running exactly your code)